# Building Spanning-tree link

Tags: cisco, switch, switching, cisco-catalyst, spanning-tree

I have two 3560 switches, and I have 2 uplinks. The goal is to make one link green on both ports on each switch, and the other link amber (standby), so when I pull the active green link out, the other standby link would take 30 seconds to be new active link. I am lost on what I am missing. I made a root switch and the VLANs and everything. I'mot sure how I make one link active and the other standby,

SleepyMan:

```
second#sh span

VLAN0005
  Spanning tree enabled protocol ieee
  Root ID    Priority    28677
             Address     001a.e3cd.9e80
             Cost        19
             Port        26 (GigabitEthernet0/26)
             Hello Time   2 sec  Max Age 20 sec  Forward Delay 15 sec

  Bridge ID  Priority    28677  (priority 28672 sys-id-ext 5)
             Address     0023.abcd.b900
             Hello Time   2 sec  Max Age 20 sec  Forward Delay 15 sec
             Aging Time 300

Interface        Role Sts Cost      Prio.Nbr Type
---------------- ---- --- --------- -------- --------------------------------
Gi0/26           Root FWD 19         32.26   P2p
Gi0/28           Altn BLK 19        128.28   P2p


VLAN0010
  Spanning tree enabled protocol ieee
  Root ID    Priority    28682
             Address     001a.e3cd.9e80
             Cost        19
             Port        26 (GigabitEthernet0/26)
             Hello Time   2 sec  Max Age 20 sec  Forward Delay 15 sec

  Bridge ID  Priority    28682  (priority 28672 sys-id-ext 10)
             Address     0023.abcd.b900
             Hello Time   2 sec  Max Age 20 sec  Forward Delay 15 sec
             Aging Time 300

Interface        Role Sts Cost      Prio.Nbr Type
---------------- ---- --- --------- -------- --------------------------------
Gi0/26           Root FWD 19         32.26   P2p
Gi0/28           Altn BLK 19        128.28   P2p


VLAN0015
  Spanning tree enabled protocol ieee
  Root ID    Priority    28687
             Address     001a.e3cd.9e80
             Cost        19
             Port        26 (GigabitEthernet0/26)
             Hello Time   2 sec  Max Age 20 sec  Forward Delay 15 sec

  Bridge ID  Priority    28687  (priority 28672 sys-id-ext 15)
             Address     0023.abcd.b900
             Hello Time   2 sec  Max Age 20 sec  Forward Delay 15 sec
             Aging Time 300

Interface        Role Sts Cost      Prio.Nbr Type
---------------- ---- --- --------- -------- --------------------------------
Gi0/26           Root FWD 19         32.26   P2p
Gi0/28           Altn BLK 19        128.28   P2p


VLAN0020
  Spanning tree enabled protocol ieee
  Root ID    Priority    28692
             Address     001a.e3cd.9e80
             Cost        19
             Port        26 (GigabitEthernet0/26)
             Hello Time   2 sec  Max Age 20 sec  Forward Delay 15 sec

  Bridge ID  Priority    28692  (priority 28672 sys-id-ext 20)
             Address     0023.abcd.b900
             Hello Time   2 sec  Max Age 20 sec  Forward Delay 15 sec
             Aging Time 300

Interface        Role Sts Cost      Prio.Nbr Type
---------------- ---- --- --------- -------- --------------------------------
Gi0/26           Root FWD 19         32.26   P2p
Gi0/28           Altn BLK 19        128.28   P2p

second#





new#sh span

VLAN0005
  Spanning tree enabled protocol ieee
  Root ID    Priority    28677
             Address     001a.e3cd.9e80
             This bridge is the root
             Hello Time   2 sec  Max Age 20 sec  Forward Delay 15 sec

  Bridge ID  Priority    28677  (priority 28672 sys-id-ext 5)
             Address     001a.e3cd.9e80
             Hello Time   2 sec  Max Age 20 sec  Forward Delay 15 sec
             Aging Time 300

Interface        Role Sts Cost      Prio.Nbr Type
---------------- ---- --- --------- -------- --------------------------------
Fa0/24           Desg FWD 19         32.26   P2p
Fa0/26           Desg FWD 19        128.30   P2p


VLAN0010
  Spanning tree enabled protocol ieee
  Root ID    Priority    28682
             Address     001a.e3cd.9e80
             This bridge is the root
             Hello Time   2 sec  Max Age 20 sec  Forward Delay 15 sec

  Bridge ID  Priority    28682  (priority 28672 sys-id-ext 10)
             Address     001a.e3cd.9e80
             Hello Time   2 sec  Max Age 20 sec  Forward Delay 15 sec
             Aging Time 300

Interface        Role Sts Cost      Prio.Nbr Type
---------------- ---- --- --------- -------- --------------------------------
Fa0/24           Desg FWD 19         32.26   P2p
Fa0/26           Desg FWD 19        128.30   P2p


VLAN0015
  Spanning tree enabled protocol ieee
  Root ID    Priority    28687
             Address     001a.e3cd.9e80
             This bridge is the root
             Hello Time   2 sec  Max Age 20 sec  Forward Delay 15 sec

  Bridge ID  Priority    28687  (priority 28672 sys-id-ext 15)
             Address     001a.e3cd.9e80
             Hello Time   2 sec  Max Age 20 sec  Forward Delay 15 sec
             Aging Time 300

Interface        Role Sts Cost      Prio.Nbr Type
---------------- ---- --- --------- -------- --------------------------------
Fa0/24           Desg FWD 19         32.26   P2p
Fa0/26           Desg FWD 19        128.30   P2p


VLAN0020
  Spanning tree enabled protocol ieee
  Root ID    Priority    28692
             Address     001a.e3cd.9e80
             This bridge is the root
             Hello Time   2 sec  Max Age 20 sec  Forward Delay 15 sec

  Bridge ID  Priority    28692  (priority 28672 sys-id-ext 20)
             Address     001a.e3cd.9e80
             Hello Time   2 sec  Max Age 20 sec  Forward Delay 15 sec
             Aging Time 300

Interface        Role Sts Cost      Prio.Nbr Type
---------------- ---- --- --------- -------- --------------------------------
Fa0/24           Desg FWD 19         32.26   P2p
Fa0/26           Desg FWD 19        128.30   P2p
```

Comment: You need to describe this a little better. Are the two switches connecting to each other, or are they linking to something else?

Comment: A diagram would help.

Comment: The two switches are connecting to eachother with 2 ethernet cables plugged in to eachother( 2 uplinks) , they are both 3560 switches I have made .1q trunks on both cables on both switches

Comment: @RonTrunk so it appears that i was speaking about HSRP, do you know in context with what im trying to achieve to apply this?

Comment: I think you should ask a new question about HSRP.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing you need to do -- the switches are already running spanning tree and one port (G0/28 on the 2nd switch) is blocking.

But:

A preferred way to configure this is to create a port-channel between the two switches.  The port channel combines the two physical interfaces into one logical interface.  You get twice the bandwidth because both links are forwarding, you still get the redundancy, and you don't have the slow convergence times of spanning tree.

Here is a sample.  Do the same on both sides.

```
interface gi 0/26
channel-group 1 mode active
!
interface gi 0/28
channel-group 1 mode active
!
interface port-channel 1
switchport
switchport mode trunk
switcport trunk allowed vlan 10-20
no shut
```

Comment: but how can i make the port colour amber(blocked) and green(forwarding) for the links? so when i pull the green forwarding link, it would take 30 seconds for the amber links to turn forwarding

Comment: With a port channel, both links are forwarding and there are no blocked ports.  The two links act as one logical link.

Comment: Traffic is split between the two links.  If one link fails, all traffic flows across the remaining link with no convergence time.

Comment: do i do this for both switches? or just the one switch you recomended

Comment: Do it on both switches.

Comment: also, im getting this error here:                                                    second(config-if)#switchport mode trunk
Command rejected: An interface whose trunk encapsulation is "Auto" can not be co                          nfigured to "trunk" mode.

Comment: Edit your question to post the error.

Comment: OK add "switch trunk encap dot1q" to the port channel interface.  (you have an old switch)

Comment: Ok I made the port channels on both switches, so on the root switch there is 1 forwarding(green) port and the other is amber(blocked) however on the switch its connected to, both ports are green, I want 1 green and 1 amber each on each switch

Comment: also, there was an error which may be why,   1d02h: %EC-5-CANNOT_BUNDLE2: Fa0/26 is not compatible with Fa0/24 and will be suspended (vlan mask is diff                                                              erent)

Comment: Yes, your port channel is not up -- the physical interfaces have to be configured the same.

Comment: Also, the lights don't work the way you want.  With spanning tree, only one port is blocked.  The other side of the link is forwarding, so it is green.  The root switch is always forwarding, so the lights are always green.

Comment: @Stan234, both links on the root switch are designated ports, and they will forward. STP only allows one root port on a non-root switch, and it will forward, but the other ports will block. That is how STP works. A port channel will fool STP into thinking that both ports are a single port, and they will both forward because STP is running on the channel port.

Comment: ok i get that now thank you, so when you say the physical interfaces have to be same, do you mean the actual port numbers have to be in the same number for each switch? or do you mean the same vlans with same id have to be on both switches?

Comment: I mean the configuration has to be the same

Comment: so i made ports f0/24, f0/26 a port-channel 1 and as well on the other switch for gi0/26, gi0/28 and now all the port lights are green strangely. I have put the output of all configuration details on the post, please let me know what you think may be wrong

Comment: That is the way it is supposed to be.  Both links are forwarding

Comment: but i want 1 link to be amber and the other to be green, do you know how i can do that, where if i unplugged the active link, the amber link would than turn green after 30 seconds

Comment: Why do want one link not to be used?

Comment: because i want an active/standby link so if one link goes down, other one will turn on

Comment: Both links are active. If one fails all traffic uses the remaining link.

Comment: how do i set it in a way where, all traffic goes on 1 link and the other link is on standby until the other link fails, i know this way is more redundant but this is what im trying to accomplish

Comment: In that case, go back to your original configuration. That is how it was working originally

Comment: yeah but than i had 3 green ports and 1 amber , i want 1 link with both ports green and other link both ports amber, is it possible to make 2 port channels possibley? would that make it happen

Comment: Spanning tree blocks ports, not links.  You will never have both ends of the link in a blocking state-that's not how spanning tree works.

Comment: ok, i agree. putting stp out of the equation for a moment, is there a way to make 1 link amber and the other green though? if so, what protocol/method would it be, and i still want to use the link thats amber, i just want it on standby so when i pull the active link, it turns on after 30 seconds

Comment: The amber light means the port is in stp blocking state. I don't believe there is any way to have the light mean something else.

Comment: Is this just for your own information or is there something specific you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: im trying to make a spanning-tree which i believe i did successfully, i have 2 uplinks between the 2 3560 switches and what im now trying to accomplish here is making one of the links active and the other in standby so when i unplug the active link, in 30 seconds the standby link will than be active, the tricky part here is that, both ports of the link needs to be amber and green

Comment: That can never happen.  The link can't be blocked from both sides. The links will work as you describe -- it will begin forwarding if the primary link goes down, but the root bridge ports are always forwarding.  The ports on the root bridge will always be green.

Comment: hey ron, so i added another switch, im trying to figure out how each switch elects a root port for that switch, i thought root port was only existing in the root switch? and how do you know if it should be forwarded or blocked?

Comment: I think you need to review how spanning-tree works.  Try watching this: https://networklessons.com/spanning-tree/spanning-tree-port-states/

Answer (score 1):

From your second switch:

```
Interface        Role Sts Cost      Prio.Nbr Type
---------------- ---- --- --------- -------- --------------------------------
Gi0/26           Root FWD 19        128.26   P2p
Gi0/28           Altn BLK 19        128.28   P2p
```

It clearly shows that STP is blocking one of the links for that VLAN. If you pull the plug on the forwarding link, STP will converge and begin forwarding on the blocked link. This is what you want, and it is the default behavior.

Comment: Your right, but I want to have one of the links as amber and the other as green, the blocked links as amber and the listening links as green, how do i do that?

Comment: If the lights don't look right, be sure you are in the right mode (press the mode switch on the front panel).

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are trying to do is choose which port on the two switches to be in a blocking state.

If you have two switches and they are connected to each other with two Ethernet cables, assuming the port speed are the same, which equals same cost, spanning tree will choose which path is fastest to the root bridge, by looking at the port priority and port id.

Because the BPDU's coming from the root bridge/Upstream switch that count, you need to adjust the port priority to a lower value on the root bridge side, so that the adjacent switch port will receive a lower port priority BPDU compared to the second Ethernet link, causing this to be the preferred path back to the root bridge. Which in turn would set the second port to be in a blocking state, amber LED.

To view port priority numbers, use the

**show spanning-tree** command on a Cisco switch.

You should see a list of ports and **Prio.Nbr** something like **128.24**.

To change the port priority, you can use the following:

> switch(config-if)# spanning-tree port-priority 32

The priority values are 0, 32, 64, 96, 128, 160, 192, and 224. All other values are rejected.

I hope this helps you on your quest.

SleepyMan

Comment: hey SleepyMan, i made the port priority for each port on each switch, but all 4 ports are green, could you possibley know why, did you need to see sh span output?

Comment: Did you make sure that the priority are not all the same? Yes please, post the output so I can have a better overview on what is going on. If they are all green then perhaps you are using per vlan spanning tree?

Comment: how do i use default spanning-tree so how it was set when i first turned the switches on? and i posted the output on the question

Comment: The default mode is PVST+ which seems what you are using. Did you create additional VLAN's? Each time you create a VLAN, a new instance of spanning tree is created. You are no longer seeing amber lights because each VLAN can take a different path and all links can be used. This is a good thing because it means you are not wasting any bandwidth and are not congesting a single link with all the VLAN traffic. If you want to go back to the amber LED status, you will need to remove all your VLAN's except VLAN 1 ( which you can't anyway as it is the default).